# Knockout does not update view with the observable object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Could you please help with this error? I have spent a lot of time on it, but no progress so for. Thanks!!

**Error:**

```
VM4705 knockout-debug.js:3326 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "with: function (){return currentCat }"
Message: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return clickCount }"
Message: clickCount is not defined
```

**Expected behavior:**

The program should list the cat names in the div with id **"catNames"** and update the div that has id **"cat"** with the information of the first cat from the **"data"** observable array. Next, when you click on different cat names from the names list, it should set the value of "**currentCat"** to the cat that is clicked on, which in turn should update the div with id **"cat"**.

[Link to JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejan/sqafpndh/)

**Below is my JS code:**

```
var cats = [
  {name:'cat1', photo: 'https://s20.postimg.org/owgnoq5c9/cat_1.jpg', clicks: 0 },
  {name:'cat2', photo: 'https://s20.postimg.org/f9d5f0ccp/cat_2.jpg', clicks: 0 },
  {name:'cat3', photo: 'https://s20.postimg.org/su3xe4s5l/cat_3.jpg', clicks: 0 },
  {name:'cat4', photo: 'https://s20.postimg.org/xdg5zna15/cat_4.jpg', clicks: 0 },
  {name:'cat5', photo: 'https://s20.postimg.org/78yuqivex/cat_5.jpg', clicks: 0 }
];

function CatRecord(cat){
  var self = this;
  self.catName = ko.observable(cat.name);
  self.imgSrc = ko.observable(cat.photo);
  self.clickCount= ko.observable(cat.clicks);
  };


var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
  self.data = ko.observableArray([]);

  // data
  cats.forEach(function(cat){
        self.data.push(new CatRecord(cat));
    }); // -- end of for Each

  // view 
  self.currentCat = ko.observable(self.data()[0]);

  self.setCurrentCat = function(catIndex){
    self.currentCat(self.data()[catIndex]);
  };

  // actions
  self.incrementClicks = function(){
    var clickCount = self.currentCat().clickCount();
    self.currentCat().clickCount(clickCount + 1);   
  };
 };


ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

**and the html:**

```
<body>

    <div id="catNames">
      <ul id="catList" data-bind="foreach: data">
        <li data-bind="text: catName, click:$parents[0].currentCat($index()) "></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="cat" data-bind="with: currentCat">
      <h2 id="clicks" data-bind="text: clickCount"></h2>
      <img id="photo" src="" alt="cat photo" data-bind=" click: $parent.incrementClicks,
      attr: {src: imgSrc}">

      <h4 id="name" data-bind="text: catName"></h4>
      <button type="submit">Admin</button>
    </div>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is actually with the `click` binding inside `foreach`. It should be:

```
<ul id="catList" data-bind="foreach: data">
   <li data-bind="text: catName, click:$parent.setCurrentCat"></li>
 </ul>
```

The first parameter of `setCurrentCat` is the `cat` object which triggered the event. So you don't need the `index`. You can simply do this:

```
self.setCurrentCat = function(cat){
  self.currentCat(cat);
};
```

I'm still not sure why you're getting the error for `with` binding.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/hcyu2gv5/)

Comment: it fixed it, thanks so much!
so, the "cat" objects from "foreach" implicitly gets passed to the "setCurrentCat"?

Comment: @rstreet yes ([documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-1-passing-a-current-item-as-a-parameter-to-your-handler-function)). [You can also call the function with additional parameters as well](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-2-accessing-the-event-object-or-passing-more-parameters)